# UINavigationBar without UINavigationControler Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I want to add a navigation bar to my view controller (I do not use a navigation controller) to show the page title and contain an add button. However when adding a navigation bar though the interface builder it is not showing. I am assuming it is possible to use it without a navigation controller otherwise there would be little point in allow me to drag it on to a view controller.

Comment: Did you add constraints to the navigation bar?

Comment: Does not appear to be possible, the navigation bar cannot be added inside the view controller, only inside the scene underneath the first responder

Comment: Sure you can. Works fine for me (In you question you implied that it allowed you to drag it on to your view controller -- are you saying you can't do that now?).

Comment: oh I think the issue is actually because I am using a UICollectionViewController

Comment: Yes, that is an issue since there is no view other than the collection view. If you want a navigation bar, you should change to a UIViewController with a collection view as a subview.

Comment: Thanks that worked, if you add that as an answer I will accept it